# If statement not working with gets() in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I ask the user for input like this:

```
puts "Enter num: "
num = gets()
if num == 44
  puts "Yeah" 
end
unless num == 44
  puts "No"
end
```

the output is `"No"` when I enter `44` when prompted. I can't figure out what's going on, so please help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should accept the answer that helped you by clicking the big check mark beside the answer.

Comment: Hint: what does the `s` in `gets` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ouput is "No" because when you use gets actually the input is taken as string, so a mismatch occurs. So for your logic to work you should convert it into integer

So this is the solution

```
puts "Enter num: "
num = gets().to_i
if num == 44
    puts "Yeah" 
end
unless num == 44
    puts "No"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
gets.to_i
```

which will essentially `chomp` the newline character and convert to integer.

Example:

```
2.1.2-perf :020 > num = gets.to_i
44
 => 44
2.1.2-perf :021 > if num == 44
2.1.2-perf :022?>       puts "Yeah"
2.1.2-perf :023?>   end
Yeah
```

Answer (score 1):

`gets()` by itself included the `newline` character. Use `gets.chomp` to remove that extra character. Then, call `.to_i` to convert to an integer. So: `gets.chomp.to_i`.

Comment: Yep, that worked! Thanks so much, I knew that it'd be a simple fix.

Comment: If you use `.to_i`, you don't need `.chomp`